# Order of \pause in beamer with tikz

Tags: tex, beamer, tikz

I reduced my problem to the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example:}

\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\pause
\draw (1,1) circle [radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\pause
Comment

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to see the following behaviour:

- Slide 1: Title "Example:"
- Slide 2: previous contents and a rectangle
- Slide 3: previous contents and a circle
- Slide 4: previous contents and "Comment"

However I get:

- Slide 1: Title "Example:"
- Slide 2: previous contents, a rectangle and "Comment"
- Slide 3: Title "Example:", a rectangle and a circle
- Slide 4: previous contents and "Comment"

In other words, "Comment" appears in slide 2 (it should not) and in slide 4 (where it should). I know that there are issues with using `\pause` within tikzpicture environment and I tried other solutions like `\only` but it did not work. Finally I split my picture in two halves and used `\vspace{-20.5mm}` between them but that's a very poor solutions for a more complicated picture which would require very fine adjustments. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks pchaigno! Your solution works nicely. Now I have to use this idea on a much more complicated case, but I'm sure it will work too.

Comment: Could you accept the answer? Do you want me to detail something?

Comment: Your answer was perfect. Thanks! How do I signal acceptance?

Comment: Glad I could help! See here for how to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/368164.

Answer (score 4):

To choose the order of appearance of the pauses, you can use `\onslide`:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example:}
  \onslide<2->{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
      \onslide<3->{
          \draw (1,1) circle [radius=1cm];
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \onslide<4->{
    Comment
  }
\end{frame}
```

See [this example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fwbmwnsgtxfj).

Comment: I drew things on a time line, and switching from `\only` to `\onslide` _fixes_ the horizontal axis. With `\only`, when new elements are added (stepped through), the horizontal axis for the timeline shall shift around on the slide. **`\onslide`** is the proper way to go with progressing through elements on a TIKZ plot :)